# How to remove spaces between the text and vertical bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$('#cmbColumn').editableSelect();
$('#cmbSidebar').editableSelect();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   
 <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>


<div class="tabs-outer">
  <div class="tabs-cap-top cap-top">
    <div class="cap-left"></div>
    <div class="cap-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left">
    <div class="fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right"></div>
    <div class="region-inner tabs-inner">
      <div class="tabs section" id="main">
        <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML3">
          <h2 class="title"> Search</h2>
          <div class="widget-content">
            <div id="multi-search">
              <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
                <option value="" />Columns
                <option value="apple+" />apple
                <option value="grapes+" />grapes
              </select>
              <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
                <option value="" />Sidebars
                <option value="mango+" />mango
                <option value="berry+" />berry

              </select>

              <input onclick=" getValue() " value="Filter" type="button" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <span class="widget-item-control">
                                <span class="item-control blog-admin">
                                    <a class="quickedit" href="https://www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=1273768514594589200&action=editWidget&sectionId=main" onclick=" return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML3&quot;)); " target="configHTML3" title="Edit">
                                        <img alt="" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" height="18" width="18" />
                                    </a>
                                </span>
          </span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs section" id="main"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
    <div class="cap-left"></div>
    <div class="cap-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
 function getValue() {
     var valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value;
     var valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;

    valOutput = "label:"+valcmbColumn+"|label:"+ valcmbSidebar;
    window.open("http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in//search/?q=" + valOutput, "_self");
  }
</script>
```

I have implemented [Jquery editable select](https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select) in my [blog](http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/)  my problem is i want to remove the white spaces `http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/search/?q=label:apple%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20|label:mango`

I mean actual one is below and see [this](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-84_iFNkzuGg/V6BHBc3_2AI/AAAAAAAAAD0/NemI3fTsllc-LVaTulmqqng1gflibpgcACLcB/s1600/20160802_114358.gif) image to understand the problem clear

```
http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/search/?q=label:apple|label:mango
```

I have came to know this space problem is due to text and vertical bar if iam not wrong. 
[image]

Comment: you need to share some relevant code ( HTML CSS JQ ) if you want our help.

Comment: oh sorry i will update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim()` to remove any white space

```
valOutput = "label:"+valcmbColumn.trim()+"|label:"+ valcmbSidebar.trim();
```

Comment: i will check again

Comment: can u explain me i mean i want to know about this function trim(); it wont effect other codes........? can u explain about this more i want to know about it

Comment: trim just removes the spaces from the start and the end of a string http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: by viewing it it is javascript or jquery code right can we do other way by css .......?

Comment: css doesn't have trimming functions

Answer (score 0):

You simply have spaces after your options value. Also, not closing your `option` tags may be a problem.

You should change this :

```
<option value="apple+" />apple
```

To this :

```
<option value="apple+">apple</option>
```

Comment: chaimillard my blog wont support closing after it takes /> because it is xml it is blogger ...... platform any other way to do with css .....?

Comment: @overflowstack9 see my answer

Comment: In my answer I don't use /> AND </. I use > and </.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard actually my blog takes <option value="apple+" />apple  because it wont support the option tag close at the end like this </option>